# Are high-dimensional versions of NTRU cryptosystem more secure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

The basis for this question is a 1-dimensional [NTRU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTRUEncrypt) cryptosystem.
After some literature inspection I have found out it can be also generalised into higher algebras: quaternions ([QTRU](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/386.pdf)) and octonions ([OTRU](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ebrusso/cryptographyORTU.pdf)) while keeping the same logic of operations in a modular quotient ring. One may therefore encrypt multiple messages at once. It appears to me that such a system, based on an algebra of dimension $2^x$, should be more secure than parallel encryption of $2^x$ messages due to obvious cross-dependence inside each element. However, I cant really put my finger on it... If so - maybe it is even better to split a given message $M$ into separate $2^x$ chunks, treat those chunks as separate messages: $m_1...m_{2^x}$ and encrypt in a higher algebra?

Could someone please help me out in nailing down the security benefits of a high-dimensional NTRU variants?